# Why serialize() have terrible performance php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I try to store multi array in mysql. serialize() and unserialize() work fine but loading time of page increase significantly... like very long and very bad even with small array with 20-50 objects.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

My issue is I have a long code with function but dont remember the array after the code :

for exemple

```
  function {

  // There is very long code here with foreach, loop and all that crap.

  // Working and displaying array

  $finalarray = ($array["stuff"]);
  print_r($finalarray);


  }

  // Here after function the variable is forgotten and print_r($finalarray) dont work anymore
```

Why the variable is unset after function because this is why I want to store it in mysql in the first place maybe i can avoid that by just remember the array.

I did not put all the code because its huge but if you need anymore information about my issue just let me know.

Thanks !

Comment: is the `$finalarray` defined before assigned values?

Comment: Thanks for the reply I really dont know $finalarray output me very good array in function but outside the function its forgotten. I need the function on top of my page and cant repeat it twice because of error. I really need to find a way to 1- store it in mysql or 2- remember the array in variable for later use in html.

Comment: I try storing it in mysql with serialize but the performance are terrible i think about creating 2 hundred colonum in mysql table and add them one by one but its terrible idea becaue sometime i have 1 thousand object in the array :)

Comment: since i use the same variable in the same page its probably completly useless to store it in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking about is called "*variable visibility scope*".
In PHP if you define a variable within a function, it will NOT be visible after the function ended.

To make the variable you create available after the function execution for the outside code to access, you have to declare it `global`, like this:

```
function f() 
{
    global $finalarray;
    ...
    $finalarray = ......;
}

f();
print_r($finalarray);
```

Another way to do it is to make the function `return` the array. Like this:

```
function f() 
{
    $finalarray = ......;  // local variable
    return $finalarray;    // return by value
}

$finalarray = f();     // becomes a global variable
print_r($finalarray);
```